# facebook - share content dynamically created by the user

Tags: ajax, facebook, share, facebook-like

Searching for the answer to this made me understand it's quite a challenge, so thumbs up for the answer (hopefully..)

After the page is loaded in my site, the user can choose items, for example - banana, pepper, tomato. When he'll click 'share' or 'like', I want this list be published on his wall. Trouble is, the meta tags are only loaded once, when the page is loaded, BEFORE any items have been chosen.

How can this be done?

Comment: Sounds like you need to write some JS or server-side code. What do you mean the "meta tags" are only loaded once? Why can't you access the attribute they've selected?

Comment: Code is what I'm seeking.. As far as I know, changing the meta tags with JS after loading won't affect the info sent to facebook when clicking 'share'